# Cant get image to display when sharing to Facebook with "og:image" property within entry tag

Tags: facebook, social

I have my "og:image" property within entry tag like this

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" limit="1" status="open" require_entry="yes" orderby="date" sort="desc" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|trackbacks" dynamic="yes" show_future_entries="yes" show_expired="yes"}
     <meta property="og:image" content="{images limit="1"}{image}{/images}" />
     <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="{images limit="1"}{image}{/images}" />
     <meta property="og:image:width" content="1200" />
     <meta property="og:image:height" content="630" />
     <meta property="og:image:alt" content="alternative" />
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Im using a "Social Bookmarks" addon and the review before posting comes out displaying the image but when I post the image is absent.

If I run the page url through Facebook's Sharing Debugger it states that the image is present and no problems were found but it also throws up one issue:

Warnings That Should Be Fixed

Inferred Property - The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for any help, Paul :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to re-scrape the page in FB debugger?